# Calculate accumulation since reset event in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'runner':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'date':['2017-04-01','2018-04-20','2018-05-25','2015-04-05','2015-10-20','2016-11-29'],'cum_distance':[100,125,130,10,20,50],'reset_event':[1,0,1,1,1,0]})

    runner  date        cum_distance    reset_event
0   1       2017-04-01  100             1          
1   1       2018-04-20  125             0          
2   1       2018-05-25  130             1          
3   2       2015-04-05  10              1          
4   2       2015-10-20  20              1          
5   2       2016-11-29  50              0
```

Data is already grouped by runner and sorted by date. 'cum_distance' is total accumulated distance.

I would like to calculate an accumulated distance per runner since the reset point:

```
    runner  date        cum_distance    reset_event runner_dist_since_reset
0   1       2017-04-01  100             1           100
1   1       2018-04-20  125             0           25
2   1       2018-05-25  130             1           30
3   2       2015-04-05  10              1           10
4   2       2015-10-20  20              1           10
5   2       2016-11-29  50              0           30
```

How I can make such calculation?
To make it easier to understand
You can treat 'runner' as a Car, 'reset_event' as a refueling. I need to calculate distance since last refuel.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Shoudnt row 3 be -120?

Comment: Corrected row 2 distance since reset to: 30 (130 - 100). Thank you.

Comment: Then I dont understand... So IMO after each reset point you would do(for example for the last rows): (50-20) for the last row, (20-10) for the one before that and (10-130) for the one before. The first one should be 130, in the same way that row 1 is 100. Can you please helpo me understand

Comment: Yatu, please notice that there are different runners. Your logic is ok but I would like to calculate the progress per runner.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Just left now give me a little while and will try to fix with what u just told me

Comment: Updated the solution. In that case row 3 should be 130 (as you had it before), because even though it is the same runner, it should be resetted as there is a 0 in `reset_event ` in the row above

Comment: Row 0: runner #1 made 100 distance and reset his progress afterwards. Row 1: runner #1 made 25 without reset. Row 3: runner #1 made 5 more so it means he made 30 since he'd made reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I managed to solve my issue.
Here are the steps:

If first runner's row does not start with 0 you will have to add dummy row with cum_distance = 0 for proper calculation. You can delete it afterwards:

```
#unique runners ids
idx = np.unique(df.runner.values, return_index=1)[1]

for i in idx:  
    if df.loc[i,'cum_distance']!=0:
        df.loc[df.shape[0]]=[df.loc[i,'runner'],pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'),0,0] #adding a row

df.sort_values(['runner', 'date'], ascending=[True, True],inplace=True)        

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)#reset index
```

Calculate distance diff for every row (first row NaN filled with cum_distance):

```
df['runner_dist_since_reset'] = df.groupby('runner')['cum_distance'].diff().fillna(df['cum_distance'])
```

Output:

```
    runner  date        cum_distance  reset_event   runner_dist_since_reset
0   1       2017-04-01  100           1             100.0
1   1       2018-04-20  125           0             25.0
2   1       2018-05-25  130           1             5.0
3   2       2015-04-05  10            1             10.0
4   2       2015-10-20  20            1             10.0
5   2       2016-11-29  50            0             30.0
```

Use reset_event tag as a clock reset:

```
df.loc[:, 'runner_dist_since_reset'] = df.groupby(['runner', df['reset_event'].shift().cumsum()])['runner_dist_since_reset'].cumsum().fillna(df['cum_distance'])
```

Output:

```
    runner  date        cum_distance  reset_event   runner_dist_since_reset
0   1       2017-04-01  100           1             100.0
1   1       2018-04-20  125           0             25.0
2   1       2018-05-25  130           1             30.0
3   2       2015-04-05  10            1             10.0
4   2       2015-10-20  20            1             10.0
5   2       2016-11-29  50            0             30.0
```

[Yatu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9698684/yatu), credit to you for showing me the 'cumsum' function.