# MySQL - Calculate accumulation since reset event in a Table

Tags: mysql, sql

This issue is a reference for my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145614/calculate-accumulation-since-reset-event-in-a-data-frame)

Python solution has been done based on extract from MySQL DB (5.6.34) where original data are stored.
My question is: Is it possible to make such calculation straight in MySQL?

Just to remind:
There is 'runners' table with accumulated distance per runner and reset tags

```
    runner  startdate   cum_distance    reset_event
0   1       2017-04-01  100             1           
1   1       2018-04-20  125             0           
2   1       2018-05-25  130             1           
3   2       2015-04-05  10              1           
4   2       2015-10-20  20              1           
5   2       2016-11-29  50              0
```

I would like to calculate an accumulated distance per runner since the reset point (my comments in brackets ()):

```
    runner  startdate   cum_distance    reset_event runner_dist_since_reset
0   1       2017-04-01  100             1           100     <-(no reset since begin)
1   1       2018-04-20  125             0           25      <-(125-100)
2   1       2018-05-25  130             1           30      <-(130-100)
3   2       2015-04-05  10              1           10      <-(no reset since begin)
4   2       2015-10-20  20              1           10      <-(20-10)
5   2       2016-11-29  50              0           30      <-(50-20)
```

So far I was able to calculate only differences between reset events:

```
SET @DistSinceReset=0;

SELECT
runner,
startdate,
reset_event,
IF(cum_distance - @DistSinceReset <0, cum_distance, cum_distance - @DistSinceReset) AS 'runner_dist_since_reset',
@DistSinceReset := cum_distance AS 'cum_distance'
FROM
runners
WHERE  
reset_event = 1
GROUP BY runner, startdate
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Which MySQL version?

Comment: Currently I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0

Comment: Ok, I have checked version of my MySQL database: 5.6.34-log

Comment: I'd go with a correlated subquery! (In the select list.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for MySQL 8.

The information you want is the most recent `cum_distance` for each user with `reset_event = 1`.  You are using MySQL 8, so you can use window functions.

Here is one method:

```
select r.*,
       (cum_distance - coalesce(preceding_reset_cum_distance, 0)) as runner_dist_since_reset
from (select r.*,
             min(cum_distance) over (partition by runner order by preceding_reset) as preceding_reset_cum_distance
      from (select r.*,
                   max(case when reset_event = 1 then start_date end) over
                       (partition by runner
                        order by start_date
                        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                       ) as preceding_reset
            from runners r
           ) r
     ) r;
```

Comment: I'm little bit confused. I'm using 8.0 Workbench but MySQL server version is 5.6.34 .Your query gives me an error on first select: "select" is not valid at this position for this server version. So it means that window functions are not supported?

Comment: what would be the answer for older MySQL version?